# How to get part of filename into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a lot of `.csv` files and I'd like to parse the file names.

The file names are in this format:

```
name.surname.csv
```

How can I write a function that populates two variables with the components of the file name?

```
A = name
B = surname
```

Comment: errr `"name.surname.csv".split(".")`

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.split` and unpack the result in `A`, `B` and another "anonymous" variable to store (and ignore) the extension.

```
filename = 'name.surname.csv'
A, B, _ = filename.split('.')
```

Comment: adding a little more explanation would make a good answer. code-only answers are less useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the name is split by `.` and stored in A and B

```
a="name.surname.csv"
A,B,C=a.split('.')
```

Of course, this assumes that your file name is in the form `first.second.csv`

Answer (score 1):

If the file names always have the exact same form, with exactly two periods, then you can do:

```
>>> name, surname, ext = "john.doe.csv".split(".")
>>> name
'john'
>>> surname
'doe'
>>> ext
'csv'
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that's when my file's name is a string, so I need somehow add it there, yes?

Comment: @yabashist Right, I assumed you had a string, so insert the code where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use str.split() method and this function.

```
def split_names(input:str):
    splitted = input.split(".")
    return splitted[0], splitted[1]

A, B = split_names("name.surname.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

First find all the files in your directory with the extention '.csv', then split it by '.'

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        # print the file name
        print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
        # split the file name by '.'
        name, surname, ext = file.split(".")
        # print or append or whatever you will do with the result here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have file saved at a specific location in the system , then you have to first get only the file name :

```
# if filename = name.surname.csv then discard first two lines
filename = "C://CSVFolder//name.surname.csv"
absfilename = filename.split('//')[-1]
# by concept of packing unpacking
A,B,ext = absfilename.split('.')
```

else you can just provide

```
A,B,ext = "name.surname.csv".split('.')
print A,B,ext
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: `filename = "C://CSVFolder//name.surname.csv"` whaaaat? and the tuple part is unneccessary as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Thanks Updated the answer

Comment: do you know that windows paths don't have double _slashes_ ?

Comment: It's just the escape sequence , placed there , If you reading it via os.path , then no need of that